# onTabChanged does not always called

Tags: android

I have root tabWidget and inside one of fragment - child tabWidget.

Fragment class is:

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener{
    private TabWidget mTabs;
```

tabhost setup and set listener in onCreateView():

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(...
...
    mTabs = (TabWidget)  view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost_top);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mTabHost.setup();
```

in the class override onTabChange method:

```
@Override public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {
```

when currrent fragment is set as selected called:

```
@Override public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser == true) { 
        mTabs.setCurrentTab(0);
        ...
    }
```

Problem:

When fragment is set visibled(tap on tab) - on child tabWidget selected is 0 item index.

## 1 try:

1. selected 0 index, tap on 2 or 3 - onTabChanged() NOT called
2. selected 0 index, tap on 1 - ok
3. selected 1 index, tap on 0 - ok
4. selected 0 index, tap on 2 or 3 - ok

## 2 try:

1. selected 0 index, tap on 2 - onTabChanged() NOT called
2. selected 0 index, tap on 2 - onTabChanged() NOT called
3. selected 0 index, tap on 3 - ok
4. selected 3 index, tap on 2 - ok

Why on the first steps onTabChanged() was not called?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Gaurav nope, solution was not found